# QtGui.QInputDialog.getText default value

Tags: qt, python-3.x

i want to make an input dialog with default value "/" on QInputDialog.getInt it works by adding the number as parameter. doesnt work for me with getText.

Using Python3.4 and PyQt4

Works:

```
port,port_check = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self,"FTP-Server Port","FTP-Server Port (meist 21):",21)
```

Doesnt work

```
pfad, pfad_check = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTP-Server Verzeichnis', 'FTP-Server Verzeichnis ( / ):','/')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

works with:

pfad, pfad_check = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FTP-Server Verzeichnis', 'FTP-Server Verzeichnis ( / ):',text='/')